# Youtube player api / Video unavailable watch on YouTube / localhost success but IP connection error

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, localhost, ip

My problem is exactly this
I'm playing a live stream on a website using the youtube player api. If my website
If I log in via localhost:8081, it works fine.
but
When I work on an IP like 192-168-xx-xx, which is the IP where my website runs
"Video unavailable
Watch on YouTube"
I get an error
My Youtube player code is as below

```
player = new YT.Player('player', {
                     height: '100%',
                     width: '100%',
                     videoId: '-Lrxv1_i3qc',
                    playerVars: {
                       'autoplay': 1,
                       'showinfo': 0,
                       'modestbranding': 1,
                       'origin': '192.168.xx.xx:8081',
                     },
                     events: {
                         'onReady': startVideo,
                         'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                     }
                 });
```

How do I solve my problem
Thanks

//It gives an error whether I use the origin or not.

last status:I noticed that there is no problem in some YouTube videos, I think the problem is in live broadcasts.
But the problem continues like this
If I connect as localhost, every video works without any problems. If I connect via IP, some videos give errors.